# In gatling, I got an error with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: gatling

When I run Engine.scala under the scala directory，it gives an error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Engine$.delayedEndpoint$Engine$1(Engine.scala:7)
    at Engine$delayedInit$body.apply(Engine.scala:4)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at Engine$.main(Engine.scala:4)
    at Engine.main(Engine.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.gatling.commons.util.PathHelper$.url2path(PathHelper.scala:34)
    at IDEPathHelper$.<init>(IDEPathHelper.scala:7)
    at IDEPathHelper$.<clinit>(IDEPathHelper.scala)
    ... 11 more
```

And BaiduHomePageSimulation.scala is:

```
package test.scala

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class BaiduSimulation extends Simulation {
    // Set the root path of the request
    val httpConf = http.baseUrl("https://www.baidu.com")
    /*
    run 10 seconds, during：the default unit is seconds, if you want to use microseconds eg. during(100 millisecond)
    */
    val scn = scenario("BaiduSimulation").during(10){
        exec(http("baidu_home").get("/"))
    }
    // set the thread count
    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(10)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

I don't konw how to fix it? Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error and was able to resolve it by marking the scala directory as Test Sources Root

Right click scala folder > Mark directory as > Test Sources Root

Comment: I had to mark the "Test" folder which includes the "Scala" folder as "Test Sources Root" to make it work